# Update wordpress fail - There has been a critical error on your website

Tags: errors, updates

During Updates. The website halted. And when refresh. "There's critical error on website" shown.
Please help on how to fix it. Thanks. I believe many do face this problem.

> Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in
> /public_html/newsite/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php
> on line 258
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> register_block_type_from_metadata() in
> /public_html/newsite/wp-includes/blocks/archives.php:119 Stack trace:
> #0 /public_html/newsite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): register_block_core_archives('') #1
> /public_html/newsite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2
> /public_html/newsite/wp-includes/plugin.php(478):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3
> /public_html/newsite/wp-settings.php(540): do_action('init') #4
> /public_html/newsite/wp-config.php(90): require_once('/home/...') #5
> /public_html/newsite/wp-load.php(37):
> require_once('/home/theamleo/...') #6
> /public_html/newsite/wp-blog-header.php(13):
> require_once('/home/theamleo/...') #7 /public_html/index.php(17):
> require('/home/theamleo/...') #8 {main} thrown in
> /public_html/newsite/wp-includes/blocks/archives.php on line 119

Comment: Your install is broken because an update did not complete. You will need to perform a manual update: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: The first error, about `create_function()` is completely separate, and is caused by your `revslider` plugin being out of date.

Comment: Thanks all. Once I performed the manual update again, the problem went settled. Yes rev slider is the main culprit and it has always been a problem during wordpress update

Comment: You should look to replace Rev Slider with something different - I know everyone likes it because it's a nifty tool with a slick interface but I've yet to find a site that isn't having serious issues that stem from RevSlider.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because of the 'Revolution Slider' plugin.

The function create_function is outdated and shall be updated with the latest version.

Simply put - Update the Revolution Slider plugin through CPanel or FTP. It shall mostly solve the problem immediately.

Then you can try to see whether you are able to access the site or not.

Also as suggested perform the manual update to make sure everything is upto date - https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: Thanks all. Once I performed the manual update again, the problem went settled. Yes rev slider is the main culprit and it has always been a problem during wordpress update